# Removendo casas decimais regulartable() pacote flextable {R}

Tags: r, rmarkdown

Estou fazendo um relatório em .rmd para exportar para .docx e para montar as tabelas estou usando o pacote *"flextable"* , que funciona para esse tipo de exportação. O problema é que quando eu vou montar as tabelas a função adiciona três casas decimais e eu não consigo remover. Exemplo:

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(0,1,2,3,4,5), b = c("x", "y", "z", "w", "j", "k"))

df %>%
flextable::regulartable()
```

Como eu posso retirar as casas decimais da coluna a ?

Comment: Coloca as.integer()

Comment: Manoel, essa funcionou perfeitamente, obrigada!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aparentemente o `flextable` não permite que tu formate o número de casas decimais do output dos números. Mas nada nos impede de usar a função `formatC` para isso:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(flextable)

df <- data.frame(a = c(0,1,2,3,4,5), b = c("x", "y", "z", "w", "j", "k"))

df %>% 
  mutate(a=formatC(a, digits=0)) %>% 
  regulartable()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu simplesmente adicionei uma linha extra ao teu código. Antes de gerar a tabela propriamente dita, eu substituí a coluna `a` por ela mesma, mas formatada para exibir 0 dígitos. Eu poderia ter colocado outros valores para o argumento `digits` a fim de formatar o número com o número de casas decimais que eu desejasse.

Comment: Legal , eu estava usando o round e não estava funcionando. Obrigada

Comment: Então Marcus, isso funciona com o meu exemplo fictício mas não funciona com o meu problema real. No meu problema real, quando eu uso o regulartable o número final fica assim: _1659.000_ , mas quando eu aplico o formatC com o mutate_if  - mutate_if(is.numeric,funs(formatC(., digits=0)))  - ele me retorna _2e+03_ . Voc:E sabe me dizer o que pode estar acontecendo ?

Comment: Use `formatC(a, digits=0, format="d")`.